# Linking a shared library to a static libtool library using automake

Tags: automake, libtool

I have this directory structure

```
prog/libA
prog/libB
```

In libA, I have a Makefile.am that looks like this:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libA.la
libA_la_SOURCES = ...
libA_la_LIBADD = ... $(LAPACK)
```

where LAPACK is my system's lapack installation. This works as expected. However, in libB I have this:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libB.la
bin_PROGRAMS = compLibB
libB_la_SOURCES = ...
compLibB_SOURCES = ...
libB_LIBADD = $(top_builddir)/libA/libA.la ...
compLibB_LDADD = libB.la
```

which does not work. The linking stage of compLibB complains about undefined references to LAPACK unless I change the last line to

```
compLibB_LDADD = libB.la $(LAPACK)
```

but that seems redundant. Haven't I already linked in `$(LAPACK)` when I build the `libA.la` convenience lib? It's unclean because now compLibB has to concern itself with the details of libA. Is there no way to link in the LAPACK libs at the libA build stage so that I don't have to re-specify it at the compLibB build stage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux equivalent of Windows DLL forwarders or MacOS reexport\_library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764734/linux-equivalent-of-windows-dll-forwarders-or-macos-reexport-library)

Comment: It is supposed to work! For example, this same approach is used in the xapian omega app (http://xapian.org/docs/xapian-omega-1.2.21/NEWS). But it does not -- I'm running in the same problem as described in the question while trying to build the omega application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Haven't I already linked in $(LAPACK) when I build the libA.la convenience lib?

As your linker has already told you, no. `libA.la` being a convenience library is somewhat like a static library (a collection of object files).

> It's unclean because now compLibB has to concern itself with the details of libA. Is there no way to link in the LAPACK libs at the libA build stage so that I don't have to re-specify it at the compLibB build stage?

You shouldn't need to specify the LAPACK libs when `libA.la` is built because the final link hasn't happened yet.  There's no way I know of accomplishing what you want without making `libA` a shared library.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually supposed to work, as the `_LIBADD` is intended to make the dependency transitive and working. On the other hand, you may have a different problem for using `$(top_builddir)`, as libtool handles differently libraries that are linked in with relative paths and with absolute ones.