# clang appears not to be linking to a library

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

I boiled down the problem to the following example:

```
int main()
{
    try {
        throw false;
    } catch (bool x)
    {
        if (x)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

generates the following errors on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adf42fbd79482935):

```
/tmp/main-c8b47a.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `typeinfo for bool'
/tmp/main-c8b47a.o: In function `GCC_except_table0':
main.cpp:(.gcc_except_table+0x30): undefined reference to `typeinfo for bool'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Cmd line:

> clang++ -std=c++11  -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

This sounds like it's not linking to a library.  Does anyone know which and what the command line switches would be?  I've not used clang before.  This works under g++.

This is the output with the -v switch:

```
clang version 3.6.0 (tags/RELEASE_360/final 235480)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.1.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/local/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -target-linker-version 2.22 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.6.0 -internal-isystem /usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.6.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -O2 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /tmp/1441759762.34715 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -pthread -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o /tmp/main-47c098.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 3.6.0 based upon LLVM 3.6.0 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.6.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0 -L/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../../lib64 -L/usr/local/bin/../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../.. -L/usr/local/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/main-47c098.o -lc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/main-47c098.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `typeinfo for bool'
/tmp/main-47c098.o: In function `GCC_except_table0':
main.cpp:(.gcc_except_table+0x30): undefined reference to `typeinfo for bool'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: How did you install Clang and libc++? Do you know which ABI library Clang is using? Can you try adding e.g. `-lc++abi`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I didn't install.  I got the link to an online compiler from SO.  Looks like if I remove `-stdlib=libc++`, it works. Hmmmm.  Why would that be?

Comment: Adding the switch you specified didn't work either.  Error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++abi`

Comment: Compiler can be found here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you need to add `-lsupc++` after main.cpp (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08f8239a7db8495c)*):

```
clang++ -std=c++11  -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lsupc++
                                                                         ^^^^^^^^
```

As  Andre Kostur  notes the [libc++ documentation](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) recommends the following, although I can not seem to get this to work on Coliru:

> Unfortunately you can't simply run clang with "-stdlib=libc++" at this
>   point, as clang is set up to link for libc++ linked to libsupc++. To
>   get around this you'll have to set up your linker yourself (or patch
>   clang). For example,
>
> - clang++ -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp -nodefaultlibs -lc++ -lcxxrt -lm -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc
>
> Alternately, you could just add libcxxrt to your libraries list, which
>   in most situations will give the same result:
>
> - clang++ -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp -lcxxrt

This looks related to issues being discussed in this thread [Making libc++ on Linux user-friendly](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Making-libc-on-Linux-user-friendly-td4038688.html), with selective quotes below:

> Here's the problem: when building libc++, the linker finds the various
>   ABI functions in libstdc++, and is quite happy with them being there.
>   When Clang calls the linker for the actual program, though, it doesn't
>   pass along a link flag for libstdc++, only for libc++. Thus, the links
>   fails.

and:

> This again can be worked around by explicitly specifying linking against the source library, and here -lsupc++ works.

Also see [Linux equivalent of Windows DLL forwarders or MacOS reexport_library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22764734/1708801).

Comment: Interesting that the clang folks (at http://libcxx.llvm.org/) advocate using a different command line:

    `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp -nodefaultlibs -lc++ -lcxxrt -lm -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc`
    Alternately, you could just add libcxxrt to your libraries list, which in most situations will give the same result:
    `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp -lcxxrt`

Comment: @AndreKostur I added that note, to my answer but it does not work for Coliru though, not clear to me why.